# Upload multiple files through a single file dialog?

Tags: 7, webforms, files

In a Webform, I want to let the user upload multiple files via one call of the file dialog. I found the following modules.

- [Webform Multiple File Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_multifile)
- [Webform Multiple File](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_multiple_file)

With either of them, I cannot open the file dialog once and select all the files. Instead, I need to open the file dialog again for every file.

Is there a way to allow file uploads in one go for Webform forms?

Comment: Did you find answer how to get file dialog only one time and select all the files at once in webform file field ???

Comment: I can't really remember – I think I didn't, otherwise I'd have given an answer myself here.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try [Multiupload Filefield Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget) and or [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget)

I think those modules can help you.